# Handler and postDelayed doesn't work if milliseconds number is too high

Tags: android

I am trying to execute a service in the background. This service is started on boot and its function is to execute something every 8 hours. In this case it sends a file by mail using JavaMail API and gmail account. This is my code:

```
private Handler mHandler;
private Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        new MailSenderActivity.MailSender().execute();


        queueRunnable();
    }
};

private void queueRunnable() {


    mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 28800000); 
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    mHandler = new Handler();
    queueRunnable();       
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //code to execute when the service is shutting down
}
@Override
public void onStart (Intent intent, int startid) {
    //code to execute when the service is starting up
}
```

If `xxxx` in `mHandler,postDelayed(updateRunnable, xxxx)` is 600000 (10 minutes in milliseconds), it runs perfectly, but it doesn't if it is 28800000 (8 hours in milliseconds)

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Only use postDelayed() and AsyncTasks if you want to delay code. If you need a bigger delay than 15 minuts use A AlarmManager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to execute a service in the background. This service is started on boot and its function is to execute something every 8 hours.

Please don't do that. Please use `AlarmManager` to start an `IntentService` every 8 hours. That way, your service does not have to stay around in memory all that time.

> If "xxxx" in "mHandler,postDelayed(updateRunnable, xxxx)" is 600000 (10 minutes in milliseconds), it runs perfectly, but it doesn't if it is 28800000 (8 hours in milliseconds)

Quite possibly, Android terminated your process. Again, this is not a problem if you use `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`.